# VMware 12 player says version.dll is corrupted

Tags: windows-10, vmware

I'm using Windows 10 with VMware 12 player. I had trouble today with it saying version.dll is corrupt so I removed VMware and re-installed it. But I still get that error.

I have tried to use the Windows Repair feature but that won't restore version.dll so then I tried to copy a version.dll from another W10 but Windows will not let me copy that to my c:\windows\system32 folder ... even if I use safe mode.

Does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: That version is too old for Windows 10. The newest version is V15.5 and you should get the newer version.

Answer (score 0):

Version 15 has problems so I stick with version 12. I found the problem ... it is not due to the host systems nor is it due to VMware, it is due to the VM being corrupt. I simply deleted the VM and reloaded XP and it is fine.